# Grub "no such device" error does not correspond to config

Tags: boot, grub

GRUB is failing to boot. BIOS tries to boot the second hard drive first (in Legacy Mode, and the first hard drive is Windows) but this yields a `no such device: cfb69400...` error.

The given id does not appear in `grub.cfg` or in the output of `blkid -o full -s UUID`.

`grub-install /dev/sdb` reports no errors. Grub was mistakenly installed on `/dev/sda` during an earlier install, and booting from this disk DOES work (using UEFI), but that's not what I need.

I can't understand where this nonexistant hard drive id is coming from, if `grub-install` worked and `grub.cfg` doesn't contain it.

How should I proceed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Among others this error is thrown by grub if it can't access the partition which contains the grub installation (`/boot/grub`). This could happen the grub in use is not configured like expected and therefore does not install needed modules by itself into *core.img*.

(I am not sure if this is the source of problem as the UUID should IMHO be shown using `blkid` in that case. Be sure to run `blkid` as root to show current information.)

To install the needed module(s) into *core.img* use something like `grub-install --modules part_msdos --root-direcotry=<installation_root> /dev/sdb`.

Use module `part_msdos` for an usual DOS partition label for example.

Be sure to configure the correct `<installation_root>` which has to be accessible when booting from your target disk.

Please refer to my answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163791/place-grub-on-virtual-disk/210497#210497 as well.